# Extract values from an xts object based on dates 'n' rows after it appears in data.frame rownames

Tags: r, sorting, indexing, xts

I thank akrun for the code below. It provides part of the solution to my problem.

```
library(xts)
data(sample_matrix)
sample.xts <- as.xts(sample_matrix, descr='my new xts object')

start_date <- '2007-01-02'
end_date <- '2007-01-05' 
col_names <- c('Open', 'High')
```

The code bellow grabs the values within the `start_date` and `end_date` pre-specified range.

```
sample.xts[paste(start_date, end_date, sep="/"), col_names]
```

What I really need is the values between `start_date + 5` and `end_date + 5` for example.

```
 sample.xts[paste(as.Date(start_date) + 5, as.Date(end_date) + 5, sep="/"), col_names]
```

The problem is that I have trading days so that excludes not only weekends but also holidays etc. For example in some cases +5 yields just 3 values because the other 2 are weekends. So I would like to make the above arbitrary of calendar days which is the format of `as.Date`. I need the next 5 values from that table rather than the next 5 calendar days.

Comment: Based on the code above, what would be the expected output.

Comment: Please actually run your code and provide the actual output. `data(sample.xts)` results in an error, and in your previous question you pasted "output" of printing a character vector as `[1] "Stock1", "Stock2", "Stock3"` but R would not put commas in the output.

Comment: 'open' and 'high' prices between 2007-01-06 and 2007-01-10. but please be aware that the sample data has calendar days and is not representative of how real financial data looks like in terms of days. this includes weekends and holidays.

Comment: just updated. forgot a few lines

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich today the internet is not working on my PC where my R console is so i have been typing most of the code in my questions. Well spotted !!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
first(sample.xts[paste0(start_date,'/')], 5)
```